# Intersection of Search Results in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a product search that is display in a Ruby on Rails application. My original model looked like this:

```
def candidates  
  @search ||= find_product.items
end 

def store
  .... Store Client ....
end 

private

def find_products
  products = store.search_products('location:"#{location}"', order: "desc") if location.present?
  products = store.search_products("#{size} ", order: "desc") if size.present?
  products = store.search_products("#{brand}", order: "desc") if brand.present?
  products
 end
```

But I thought it would be better to take the intersection of the results of from each of the attributes.

```
private


def find_products_by_location
  products = store.search_products('location:"#{location}"', order: "desc") if location.present?
end

def find_products_by_size
   products = store.search_products("#{size} ", order: "desc") if size.present?
end

def find_products_by_brand
  products = store.search_products("#{brand}", order: "desc") if brand.present?
end

def find_product
  find_products_by_location & find_products_by_size & find_products_by_brand
end
```

Unfortunately when I test in the console I get a returned value of true or false. Each individual attribute has an array of data if it is present in the form.

How can I get results of the intersection of multiple arrays?

Comment: Have you try to use scopes? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 1):

You always need to return an Array (or Set) from each of your methods:

```
def products_by_location
  if location.present?
    store.search_products('location:"#{location}"', order: "desc")
  else 
    []
  end
end

def products_by_size
  if size.present?
    store.search_products("#{size} ", order: "desc")
  else
    []
  end
end

def products_by_brand
  if brand.present?
    store.search_products("#{brand}", order: "desc")
  else
    []
  end
end

def find_product
  products_by_location & products_by_size & products_by_brand
end
```

You could also leverage some metadata-programming here:

```
def products_by(key)
  if params[key].present?
    store.search_products("#{key} ", order: 'desc')
  else
    []
  end
end

def products
  products_by(:location) & products_by(:size) & products_by(:brand)
end
```

Lastly, you should really consider pushing this code down into the model level. Having this type of logic in the controller is generally considered a bad pattern.